# Installing can I install gstreamer 1.4 on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, gstreamer

Is it possible to install gstreamer 1.4 framework on Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a PPA with gstreamer 1.4.3 for Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr).

https://launchpad.net/~ddalex/+archive/ubuntu/gstreamer

Comment: The code names are used before the Ubuntu release is shipped. Later the numbers should be used: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames

Answer (score 9):

Open your terminal and paste these line after line

```
wget http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gstreamer/gstreamer-1.4.0.tar.xz
tar -xvf gstreamer-1.4.0.tar.xz
cd gstreamer-1.4.0

./configure --prefix=/usr \
            --with-package-name="GStreamer 1.4.0 BLFS" \
            --with-package-origin="http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/" &&
make
sudo make install
```

It will install and [source](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/multimedia/gstreamer10.html)

Comment: Thx bro I have 1 one more question for you when I installed this and typed gst in terminal i got gst-inspect-1.0 there is no gst-inspect-1.4.So that means it's registred as 1.0 but how can I know that I installed 1.4? I mean how can I check version ?

Comment: If you have gstreamer 1.0 installed remove it and restart your system and try again.

Comment: I don't know is this a bug or what if I try to remove gstreamer it removes ubuntu-desktop in the process.

Comment: @Raja To verify the version number, run the following command: `gst-inspect-1.0 --version`